# Can I record device sound with AudioKit Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, audiokit

Does AudioKit provide anyway to record the internal device audio not the microphone input but the device audio in iOS using swift or Objective-C

Answer (score 2):

See [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/652490) for an official Apple response:

> The simplest solution would be to use ReplayKit to record your app and have replay kit deliver sample buffers directly to your app. (You can just ignore video and mic buffers if you don't need them.)
>
> Take at look at the WWDC video (https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10633/) at about the 8:45 mark.

Comment: I watched the video and poked around a bit and it says it will record the audio of "YOUR APP" it's mentioned a lot. But I want the whole device audio not just my app. 
Is it possible with ReplayKit if you know?

Comment: @Scatter You'll probably need to use https://developer.apple.com/documentation/replaykit/rpbroadcastsamplehandler and its companions. These are the API’s usually used for sharing your screen via apps like Zoom or Microsoft Teams.